Do I need to move all my DNS records to Route 53 when I point Godaddy to their nameservers?
I'm managing a website that is currently using Godaddy as its DNS provider. Godaddy can't point at a Cloud Front distribution, so I need to swap the DNS name servers to Route 53.
I have MX records for mail, some TXT files, and SRV files. Do I need to port all of these over into Route 53 as well?

Are you switching your zone over to Route 53 in order to distribute from the apex (i.e. the domain's top level, instead of using a redirect to a subdomain CNAME, like example.com -> www.example.com)?
If so then yes, you'll need to transfer over all records currently in your Godaddy domain to Route 53.

Yes, I have to I think, because Godaddy won't let me point at cloudfront.

What happens when you try?

It all works fine!
